# Open folder on network share in Intranet Zone

Tags: javascript, scripting, internet-explorer-11

we have the following setup:

I would like to open a folder on a network share via Internet Explorer. I've done this with the following code:

```
window.open("file://networkshare/MailImportEscape/Subfolder");
```

But sometimes the subfolder does not exists and Internet Explorer throws the error: `file:/// ... not found`

Is there any way to catch this error via javascript or something like this? Or is there a better way to open the folder? Try and catch is not working.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Highly doubt there is anything you can do from the clientside.

Comment: You should be accessing the folder on the server side.

Comment: I would like to open this folder in Windows Explorer on the client so that he can drag and drop files into the folder.